# Stably deforming vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-k-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. $V_1$ and $V_2$ are two vector bundles on $X\times \mathbb{A}^1$ such that $V_1|_{X\times \{0\}}\cong V_2|_{X\times \{0\}}$ and $V_1|_{X\times \{1\}}\cong V_2|_{X\times \{1\}}$. Is it possible to deform $V_1\oplus K$ to $V_2\oplus K$ for some vector bundle $K$? More precisely is there a vector bundle $V$ on $X\times \mathbb{A}^1\times\mathbb{A}^1$ such that $V|_{X\times \mathbb{A}^1\times\{0\}}\cong V_1\oplus K$ and $V|_{X\times \mathbb{A}^1\times\{1\}}\cong V_2\oplus K$? If so is it possible to find a deformation that it stays constant on the lines $X\times \{0\} \times \mathbb{A}^1$ and $X\times \{1\} \times \mathbb{A}^1$? ($X$ is a variety over a finite field if that matters.)

Edit 1: The answer to the first question is yes but still I don't know the answer to the second one. The conditions of the problem implies that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are equal to each other in $K_0(X\times \mathbb{A}^1)$. A trick due to Heller implies that whenever two elements in $K_0$ are equal you can find $K$ such that $V_1\oplus K$ and $V_2\oplus K$ are extensions of same two vector bundles. Now it is well known that you can deform any two extensions to each other.

Edit 2: I had another similar question, I decided to add it here instead of asking a new question. Let $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$ be vector bundles on $X$. Assume there are two different non-isomorphic short exact sequences $SE1$ and $SE2$ of the form of $0\rightarrow V_1 \rightarrow V_2 \rightarrow V_3 \rightarrow 0$. Is there a deformation (or a sequence of deformations) $SE1_t$ and $SE2_t$ both of the form $0\rightarrow V_{1t}\rightarrow V_{2t} \rightarrow V_{3t} \rightarrow 0$, such that it gives us $SE1$ and $SE2$ at $t=0$. At $t=1$ it gives us two isomorphic short exact sequences.

I'll appreciate if you have any ideas how to approach the problem.

Comment: Deforming both to the split extension gives a family over $\mathbf A^1 \amalg_{\operatorname{pt}} \mathbf A^1$, not over $\mathbf A^1$, right? But you can also do it directly because the space of extensions is an affine space.

Comment: You are correct. Even if you do both of them to the split one. You can also direct sum the split extension into the $K$. Thus you can get the desired deformation with the modified $K$.